# Which method can accurately detect circular/angular shapes?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, object-detection

Is there a method to detect shapes like these accurately and efficiently? I have tried the OpenCv Haar Casacade Classifier which does not work well. These shapes should all be the same class object and can be of different sizes and a little differently shaped (more circular or more angular). In the attached picture there are 4 separate shapes, of which 2 overlap each other.
[image: example circular/angular shapes]

Comment: hmmm I find that tricky because I haven't faced that situation before. you could try `detectMultiScale` of HOGDescriptor in combination with a custom-trained SVM for your objects  https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a91e56a2c317392e50fbaa2f5dc78d30b you'd collect a bunch of examples, best without overlap, and train the SVM on the HOG descriptors of those.

Comment: this references relevant sample code for training your own HOG detector: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a6de5ac55631eed51e36278cde3a2c159

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info